# Implementing Unity BannerView

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

Sup, I need some help about this plugin [googleads-mobile-plugins](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-plugins/)
In my game, I created a Class that holds a static variable of the bannerView. 
I made it like this so it will be loaded only once.

but first I tried putting this code from the instruction on onGui

but it makes my game lag

```
onGUI{
            bannerView = new BannerView ("123123123", AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom); 
                AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder ().Build (); 
                bannerView.LoadAd (request);
}
```

so the new version i made is like this.

```
public class MainController {

    private static BannerView bannerView;


    public static void bannerLoad()
    {
        if (bannerView == null)
        { 
            bannerView = new BannerView ("123123123", AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom); 
            AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder ().Build (); 
            bannerView.LoadAd (request);
        }
    }


    public static void bannerShow()
    {
        if (bannerView != null) 
        { 
            bannerView.Show (); 
        }
    }


    public static void bannerHide()
    {
        if (bannerView != null) 
        { 
            bannerView.Hide (); 
        }
    }

}
```

each scene has its own controller

example

```
public class Scene1Controller : MonoBehaviour
{
   onStart()
   {
      MainController.bannerShow(); 
   }

}
```

My problem is that it looks like the ads are not refreshing

I only show the ads on my menu then hide when playing

the refresh rate must only be 60 seconds but the ads are not refresh. is there something wrong with my implementation by putting it on static?

should I always send command  `bannerView.LoadAd (request);` ?

Should I send a new ad request when on every start of the scene?

```
BannerView  bannerView = new BannerView ("123123123", AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom); 
                AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder ().Build (); 
                bannerView.LoadAd (request);
```

The problems is that when the scene was loaded and the ads where still not loaded and the user exit that scene is that even count in my admob impression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you don't need to include ad code in onGUI() method.
And also, you don't need to call LoadAd again and again. In my app build with unity, the ads do refresh.  For example if there is no other ad available to show at that point of time, I guess the same ad will remain but as a new impression. Also, you can check the logcat while testing your app using Xcode ( for iOS) and Eclipse/Android Studio ( for android). It will show ad is refreshed.

Comment: hi. i need to clarify something. are you sure  I dont need to call a new adrequest? just the one I have requested at first?

Comment: Yes, buddy. This is why the refresh rate is meant. Ad automatically refreshes after the time provided by you. BTW have you checked the ad unit id on the admob website that Automatic refresh is not set to "No refresh"?

Comment: Hi. yes I checked and is set to 60 seconds. I been testing it. i don't know but the ads won't refresh if i hide them. but keeping them visible, the ads refreshes. thank you!